# Dropdown in ng-repeat going behind parent div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P64yq.png) I have a parent div which has set of drop-downs created using ng-repeat. These drop-downs are going behind and creating a scroll bar for the parent div whenever I open it. I want the drop-downs in ng-repeat to show up without creating scroll bar for parent div. Can someone help on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u give ur plunkr attachment

Comment: I can't right now.. but I can be more specific towards problem. Whenever I open any of the drop-downs, the scrollbar of the parent div increases, because of which I have to scroll down through parent div and select an option from dropdown

Comment: From Review: Please recreate the issue here in the code-runner or provide a link to code. It doesn't a have to be your full code, but the snippet to recreate or understand the issue.

Comment: yeh you can atleast provide a snippet so that we can try to help..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_select

Try to figure it out..the scenario is same but no scroll is getting created

Comment: I added an image how it looks

Comment: if u could give ur code i can easily modify and see

Comment: Your image definetely doesn't help. If you want help, you should post **at least** a line of code!